# Tonal evolution of 俘?

Tags: tones

Looking at the character『俘』

- In Soutwestern Mandarin it takes 阴平:

《现代汉语方言音库 • 成都话音档》

> 俘
> fu⁵⁵

- In Cantonese it looks to also take 阴平:

> (Jyutping): fu1

- Hokkien, also, maybe 阴平: /hu⁴⁴/.

I'm seeing some transcriptions of Middle Chinese & Old Chinese:

- phju
- /pʰɨo/
- /*pʰuw/

But I'm struggling to make much sense of how the 阴平 pk. 阳平 split came about in topolects vs. MSM.

Any ideas on the tonal evolution of 俘?

Answer (score 2):

That is a good question. I searched a bit and here is what I found:

In 1922, 趙元任's 國音新詩韻 listed 俘 as 阴平:
[image]

Note that 孚 was also 阴平 there.

1922 中華民國發音字典 also listed them as 阴平:
[image]

In 1932, 國音常用字彙 listed both 俘 and 孚 as 阳平:

[image]

Something probably happened during the 10 years. (It was a time of change and turmoil).

I would say these two characters have undergone some irregular changes in Mandarin.

Comment: Very interesting. Quite funny to see the pronunciation suddenly change over ten years.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one definitive answer to this question. It is possible that the tonal evolution of 俘 differed depending on the dialect or topolect in question.

Here is one possible scenario: In proto-Mandarin, 俘 was pronounced with a 3rd tone. However, over time, the 3rd tone gradually shifted to a 2nd tone in some dialects but remained a 3rd tone in other dialects. This is why we see two different tones (2nd and 3rd) in modern Mandarin dialects for this word.